# Why does my array editing not work correctly?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and am making a board game where the player enters how many places they want to move left/right etc. however sometimes it moves correctly and sometimes it doesn't. I think it has something to do with my grid array, but I'm not sure... Would be great if someone could help me out, thanks!

```
choice=0
b=0
oldP=0
newP=0
player_location='X'
x=8
y=0
xi=0
yi=0
up=0
down=0
left=0
right=0
new_board=[xi][yi]
gold_coins=0
bandits=5
treasure_chests=10
a=1
xi2=0
yi2=0

import random
def menu():
    print('If you would like to play the Treasure Hunt , press 1')
    choice=input('If not, press any key to exit')
    if choice=='1':
        print('Great! You have made the right choice :)')
    else:
        print('Goodbye.')
        quit()
menu()
def grid():
    new_board = [ ]

def board():
  new_board = [ ]
  top_row = [' 1 ',' 2 ',' 3 ',' 4 ',' 5 ',' 6 ',' 7 ',' 8 ']

  new_board.append(top_row)

  for x in range(0,8):
    row = [' 0 ']*8
    new_board.append(row)
  return new_board

def print_board(b):
  row_letters = [' ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
  i = 0
  for row in b:
    print (row_letters[i],''.join(row))
    i=i+1
new_board = board()
xi=int(8)
yi=int(0)
new_board[xi][yi] = player_location
print_board(new_board)
while a==1:
    upordown=input('Would you like to move up or down? Enter \'u\' for up or \'d\' for down.').lower()
    upordown=upordown.lower()
    while not (upordown== 'u' or upordown== 'd'):
        print('Invalid input. Please try again')
        upordown= input().lower()
    while upordown=='u':
        try:
            up=int(input('How many spaces would you like to move up?'))
            b=0
        except:
            print('This is not a valid input, please enter a number.')
            b=1
        if b==0:
            break
    while upordown=='d':
        try:
            down=int(input('How many spaces would you like to move down?'))
            b=0
        except:
            print('This is not a valid input, please enter a number.')
            b=1
        if b==0:
            break
    leftorright=input('Would you like to move left or right Enter \'l\' for left or \'r\' for right.').lower()
    leftorright.lower()
    while not (leftorright== 'l' or leftorright== 'r'):
        print('Invalid input. Please try again')
        leftorright= input().lower()
    while leftorright=='l':
        try:
            left=int(input('How many spaces would you like to move left?'))
            b=0
        except:
            print('This is not a valid input, please enter a number.')
            b=1
        if b==0:
            break      
    while leftorright=='r':
        try:
            right=int(input('How many spaces would you like to move right?'))
            b=0
        except:
            print('This is not a valid input, please enter a number.')
            b=1
        if b==0:
            break
    print('Okay...')

    grid()
    while True:
        board()
        player_location=' X '
        if upordown=='d' and leftorright=='l':
            new_board[y-down][x-left] = player_location
            new_board = board()
            xi2=int(xi2-left)
            yi2=int(yi2-down)
            print ("The current x location is",xi)
            print ("The current y location is",yi)
            print ("The amount you chose to go down was",down)
            print ("The amount you chose to go right was",left)
            xi = int(xi+left)
            print("The new x location is",xi2)
            yi = int(yi+down)
            print("The new y location is",yi2)
            print(' ')
            while 0>xi2 or xi2>8 or 0>yi2 or yi2>8:
                print('Your move was illegal. Please enter a move that will position you within the grid')
                left=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move right'))
                down=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move up.'))
                xi=int(xi+left)
                yi=int(yi+down)
            new_board[xi][yi] = player_location
            print_board(new_board)
            break
        elif upordown=='d' and leftorright=='r':
            new_board = board()
            xi2=int(xi2+right)
            yi2=int(yi2-down)
            print ("The current x location is",xi)
            print ("The current y location is",yi)
            print ("The amount you chose to go down was",down)
            print ("The amount you chose to go right was",right)
            xi = int(xi+right)
            print("The new x location is",xi2)
            yi = int(yi+down)
            print("The new y location is",yi2)
            print(' ')
            while 0>xi2 or xi2>8 or 0>yi2 or yi2>8:
                print('Your move was illegal. Please enter a move that will position you within the grid')
                right=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move right'))
                down=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move down.'))
                xi=int(xi+right)
                yi=int(yi+down)
            new_board[xi][yi] = player_location
            print_board(new_board)
            break
        elif upordown=='u' and leftorright=='l':
            new_board = board()
            xi2=int(xi2+left)
            yi2=int(yi2-up)
            print ("The current x location is",xi)
            print ("The current y location is",yi)
            print ("The amount you chose to go up was",up)
            print ("The amount you chose to go left was",left)
            xi = int(xi+left)
            print("The new x location is",xi2)
            yi = int(yi-up)
            print("The new y location is",yi2)
            print(' ')
            while 0>xi2 or xi2>8 or 0>yi2 or yi2>8:
                print('Your move was illegal. Please enter a move that will position you within the grid')
                left=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move right'))
                up=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move up.'))
                xi=int(xi-left)
                yi=int(yi-up)
            new_board[xi][yi] = player_location
            print_board(new_board)
            break
        elif upordown=='u' and leftorright=='r':
            new_board = board()
            xi2=int(xi2+right)
            yi2=int(yi2+up)
            print ("The current x location is",xi)
            print ("The current y location is",yi)
            print ("The amount you chose to go up was",up)
            print ("The amount you chose to go right was",right)
            xi = int(xi-right)
            print("The new x location is",xi2)
            yi = int(yi+up)
            print("The new y location is",yi2)
            print(' ')
            while 0>xi2 or xi2>8 or 0>yi2 or yi2>8:
                print('Your move was illegal. Please enter a move that will position you within the grid')
                right=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move right'))
                up=int(input('Please enter the number of moves you would like to move up.'))
                xi=int(xi-right)
                yi=int(yi-up)
            new_board[xi][yi] = player_location
            print_board(new_board)
            break
```

I have attached all my code including verification so that the user does not escape the grid as I'm not sure which parts to include to make my problem and program clear.

Comment: _"I am a beginner in Python..."_ -  Stop!  You need to take a few steps back. A project like this is not something a beginner should be trying to do.  Try something like making tic-tac-toe, and then move up.

Comment: @leaf Definitely true, a bit adventurous! However I saw this as a beginners challenge on a website and am really hoping to complete it

Comment: Define "beginner". Do mean beginner as in _Just download   Python_, or as in _I've been doing Python for a few months now_ beginner. Right now, the biggest problems I see with your code is that it is very verbose.

Comment: Check these sorts of statements `xi2=int(xi2-left); yi2=int(yi2-down)`. Be consistent to make errors more obvious. For example, you could always subtract left and down, and add right and up. In this way, you'll review your logic and make it easier to understand in the future. Also, try to see if you can find a pattern to when it works and when it doesn't. Is it always in one direction? Is it close to the edge?

Comment: @VivekChavda Thank you. Will definitely be taking your advice!

Comment: @leaf Beginner as in I've been doing Python for two months now. And yes, I agree, my program is a bit heavier than needed

Comment: I strongly recommend *incremental programming*: you write a few lines, make sure they work, and don't continue until you have the existing code correct.  That way, when something doesn't work, you know it's in the last few lines you added.  Otherwise, you get to 200 lines of code and not much clue where the error lies.

Comment: There's also a wonderful [introduction to debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Practice improvements:**

There's a wonderful introduction to debugging [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

I strongly recommend incremental programming: you write a few lines, make sure they work, and don't continue until you have the existing code correct. That way, when something doesn't work, you know it's in the last few lines you added. Otherwise, you get to 200 lines of code and not much clue where the error lies.

**Program changes**

This code hasn't been designed for debugging or maintenance; you should fix those problems before you go on.  Most of all, you've created two sets of input that perform one task (get the user's move) and then four blocks of code that perform the same task (move the user).

Instead, find some usable wording that will have the player enter the move on *one* line.  You turn that into movement coordinates (such as [1, -2] for "up one and left two"), and then use a single block of code to move through the grid.  Instead of testing four blocks of code, you test one; when you need to make a change, you make *one* change, not four copies under rotation and reflection.

**Result**
The code you live with should look more like this:

```
def get_move():
    advice  = "Please enter your move in two integers:\n" +
              "vertical, then horizontal.  Use positive numbers\n" +
              "for up and right, negative for down and left.\n"
    example = "For instance, the line \n\t2 -1\n" +
              "   is 2 spaces up, one space left."
    move = input(advice + example).split
    x_move = int(move[0])
    y_move = int(move[1])
    # Here, you check move legality; repeat until you get a legal move

    return x_move, y_move

while True:
    print_board()
    x_move, y_move = get_move()    # get_move contains the input interaction and data checking
    move(x_move, y_move)  # perform the move; update the board.
```

Also note that you should probably update the existing board, rather than (apparently) creating a new one for every move.  Stay in this loop until the game is over; don't break out on each move.

Does that move you toward a solution?

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice and tips. I will definitely be reading that introduction to debugging, and this has certainly moved me towards a solution!

Comment: Great.  When you do get to a resolution, please remember to come back here, up-vote the helpful things, and accept an answer -- even if you have to write one yourself.  That allows Stack Overflow to properly retire and archive teh question.